# XNA 4.0 WP7 Game Volume Control

Tags: windows-7, windows-phone-7, xna-4.0

I want to make a little query here before I submit my game on the app-hub. Microsoft has set strict policies regarding the music interruptions in the game, I've followed all of them except for the one that says ".../adjust the background music", though the value of the `MediaPayer` volume could be changed yet I dunno who to give this control to user in the game for adjusting it (volume). Opinions and suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement in question relates only to the initial launch of the application. If your game plays background music (by using the `MediaPlayer` class; `SoundEffect` should not be used for background music), then on initial launch, if the user is already listening to music, then you must not pause or stop the active music without first asking the user. A simple message box should suffice. It would also be friendlier to the user if you provided a setting that enabled the user to change their initial decision, so that they can switch to your game music if they chose to keep listening to their own music.